# R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, actionbarsherlock-map

I have implemented the actionbarsherlock in my project and after implementation and my project is full of errors and it is "R cannot be resolved to a variable". I have tried a lot to clear this and i cant get the solution.Please help me to solve this.

Comment: If you have an error in an XML file, the R.java file won't be generated by the resource compiler. Check the error messages.

Comment: Check your all xml files and clean your app once and build.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you your code contains errors then R.java won't generate, if the errors are about R.java then
>   Just clean the project once, and build it again. 
>   If the erorrs are  not resolved then check for the imports you may have mistakely imported android.R.java.

Comment: Thank U.I have fixed the problem.

Comment: @G.V.Raghuram. Good to know that...If you feel it helps you mark this as answer by clicking on the right mark beside the answer

Answer (score 0):

first otion is make project `clean` and `Rebuild` your project
or if there is any image `name` in `drawable`  missing in `Uppercase` or any other option with not allowed may possible to check,
or in xml layout check all files is well define and is that no `any xml error` due to this resone may `R` file is remove

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line from import section if you have "import android.R"